# Dell Latitude with Kubuntu freezes after Thunderbolt is connected

Tags: kernel, kubuntu, suspend, dell, thunderbolt

Kernel -> 4.15.0-45-generic

OS -> Kubuntu 18.04

Hardware -> Dell Latitude 5480

Docking -> Dell WD15

I get a frozen laptop immediately after the Thunderbolt is plugged in.

Removing the Thunderbolt brings the laptop back to life.

Any idea how to solve this problem running on the most recent kernel?